# Java EE + openmaple

Tags: servlets, java-ee-6, maple, servlet-listeners

At the moment I try to integrate openmaple into a Java EE Web application. I'm using Tomcat v7.0. Because of the fact that I can connect to the openmaple kernel only once I decided to start the openmaple Engine in a specific ServletContextListener which opens the Engine at the start of the server and holds it open. That works great and the Engine opens. My problem is that I get an Error when I would Like to calculate sth. with the Engine in my Servlet code. The Windows (UAC) is deactivated. Here the Error Message:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000000d66d9d1, pid=1072, tid=3008
#
# JRE version: 7.0_21-b11
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.21-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [maple.dll+0x2dd9d1]  newGMPIntFromString+0xe81
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Program Files\eclipse\hs_err_pid1072.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Can somebody please help me?

Thanks a lot!

Martin

Comment: The crash you're showing here occurs in the native-code called by the openmaple Java part and more specifically, newGMPIntFromString seems to generate an access violation.  I think this is either caused by you feeding it junk, or not using it properly in some other way, or by a bug in openmaple.  In these cases, the former option is always the first to investigate, so it could be helpful to add your application code, at least up to the point where openmaple exlodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there is no way to do this with the open maple engine so what we did is just restart the tomcat after every lookup. This was just an educational project, so that dirty fix was enough but for the future I hope that the Maple guys will fix that problem! fvu thanks a lot for you respond!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the JRE from version 1.7 to version 1.6, because Java v 1.6 is more stable and OpenMaple Java API is not updated after the first version was released in 2003 [J2SE 1.4 appeard in February 6, 2002, while J2SE 5.0 (September 30, 2004) ].